# How do I stop a window.unload event

Tags: jquery

I have two function in my JQuery that act on a user leaving the page.  The idea is that if a user leaves the page by closing the browser, we use:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
   return "Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving or submitting?";
 });
```

Now, we want to ask the user if they would like to save their progress only if they log out of the page, using:

```
$("#logoutButton").click(function(e) {
  var result = confirm("Would you like to save before logging out?");

  if(result == true) {
     $("#savebutton").click(); //simulate a click on save before redirecting
  }

  window.location.href = "www.redirectPage.com";  //go to logout page regardless of choice
});
```

Now, the problem that I am facing, is that whenever the user clicks logout, it performs the save check correctly, but it still asks the user if they want to leave the page, using the `beforeunload` method.  Is there a way to stop `beforeunload` from triggering in this case from inside the logoutbutton `click` function?

Comment: Just unbind the event handler (with `$(window).unbind('beforeunload')`) before changing `location.href`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`.unbind()`**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove all event handlers for a given event. In your code, that would be

```
$(window).unbind('beforeunload');
```

Call it right after saving:

```
$("#logoutButton").click(function(e) {
    var result = confirm("Would you like to save before logging out?");

    if(result == true) {
        $("#savebutton").click(); //simulate a click on save before redirecting
        $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    }

    window.location.href = "www.redirectPage.com";  //go to logout page regardless of choice
});
```